# Ajax action won't reflect on appearance but the value. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm using Rails3. Now trying to implement follow button in index.html.erb just like twitter.
It shows member list and their follow buttons.
It looks okay but if I press any of those follow button, appearance doesn't change.
It should changes follow to un-follow right away.
I have no idea why it does. But if I reload the page, it shows correct status.

follows_controller.rb

```
class FollowsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :action=>"create.js"}
      end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.stop_following(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :action=>"destroy.js"}
  end
end

end
```

views/users/_follow_user.html.erb

```
<% unless user == current_user %>
    <% if current_user.following?(user) %>
        <%= button_to("Un-Follow", user_follow_path(user.to_param, current_user.get_follow(user).id), 
        :method => :delete, 
        :remote => true, 
        :class => 'btn') %>
    <% else %>
        <%= button_to("Follow", user_follows_path(user.to_param), 
        :remote => true, 
        :class => 'btn btn-primary') %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

views/users/create.js.erb

```
$('.follow_user[data-user-id="<%=@user.id%>"]').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "follow_user", :locals => {:user => @user}) %>');
#jQuery
```

views/users/destroy.js.erb

```
$('.follow_user[data-user-id="<%=@user.id%>"]').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "follow_user", :locals => {:user => @user}) %>');
#jQuery
```

views/users/index.html.erb

```
<%- model_class = User.new.class -%>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.pluralize %></h1>
</div>
  <% @from %>
  <h3>tag cloud</h3>
  <% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
    <%= link_to tag.name, {:action=>'index', :tag=>tag.name}, :class => css_class%>
  <% end %> 


<%= paginate @users %>

<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>  
      <div class="memberListBox">
        <div class="memberList">
            <p class="name"><span><%= user.user_profile.nickname %></span>(<%= user.user_profile.age %>)</p>
            <p class="size"><%= user.username %></p>
            <p class="img">
            <% if user.user_profile.user_avatar? %>
            <%= image_tag(user.user_profile.user_avatar.url(:thumb),:height => 100, :width => 100, :class => 'img-polaroid' ) %>
            <% else %>
            <%= image_tag('nophoto.gif',:height => 100, :width => 100, :class => 'img-polaroid' ) %>
            <% end %>
            </p>
            <div class="introduction">
                <%= user.user_profile.introduction %>
            </div>

<% if user_signed_in? && current_user!=user %>          
  <div id="follow_user">
    <%= render :partial => "follow_user", :locals => {:user => user} %>
  </div>
<% end %>

  <%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i> ') + 'Message', new_messages_path(user.username), :class => 'btn btn-primary'  %>


                <%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> ') + 'Profile', show_user_path(:username => user.username, :breadcrumb => @from), :class => 'btn btn-info' %>              

        </div>
    </div>
   <% end %>
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

response content

`$('#follow_user').html('       <form action=\"/users/1/follows\" class=\"button_to\" data-remote=\"true\" method=\"post\"><div><input class=\"btn btn-primary\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Follow\" /><input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"G/taOUeWy2gumhWUi10cPvECAmYLQdhQ2/eGGMJwvPE=\" /><\/div><\/form>`\n');

Comment: Try firebug to track the ajax request and find response content is correct or not. If the response content is correct then copy the response content and manually execute the javascript using web console.

Comment: @Siddick Thanks I checked,and copied the response content. But how can I execute that using web console? Is it within rails?

Comment: @Siddick Yeah! please check the bottom of my question! I added response content what it gave back. So I copied it and pasted it into web console to execute. But nothing happenes:( Can you see what's wrong with my code??

Comment: @Siddick I doubt 'create.js' and 'destroy.js'. Response should have ID right behind follow_user, but it seems nothing shows up there.

Comment: check the element exist or not `$('#follow_user').length`

Comment: @Siddick if I type it into my web console, it gave back 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the user id to the attribute `data-user-id` and add the class `follow_user`

```
<div class="follow_user" data-user-id="<%= user.id %>">
  <%= render :partial => "follow_user", :locals => {:user => user} %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I did but it's still the same:( and response content gives back $('#follow_user').html('  <form action=\"/users/3/follows\" class=\"button_to\" data-remote=\"true\" method=\"post\"><div><input class=\"btn btn-primary\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Follow\" /><input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"G/taOUeWy2gumhWUi10cPvECAmYLQdhQ2/eGGMJwvPE=\" /><\/div><\/form>\n');

Comment: whether the `views/users/create.js.erb` and `views/users/destroy.js.erb` contains  `$('.follow_user[data-user-id="<%=@user.id%>"]')` ?

Comment: both of those js files contains that in head part

Comment: check the view files in **views/follows** contains `$('.follow_user[data-user-id="<%=@user.id%>"]')`

Comment: @HUSTEN Note that @Siddick is pointing out `#follow_user` (ID selector) should be `.follow_user` (class selector).

Comment: @siddick ahhh!! That's it!!!!!  there was dupulicated js in views/follow!!! right! It's working perfect after I modified that js files! Thanks!!! so js files in views/users shouln't exist???

Comment: Views for `UsersController` actions belong in `views/users`. The controller in question is `FollowsController` and Rails expects it's views to be in `views/follows`. See how the controller and view folder names go together?