# Why Ajax won't reflect on show but index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Now if I press follow on index page, the button changes 'follow' to 'un-follow' right away. 
But, at show page, nothing won't happen. 
How can I fix this??

views/users/show.html.erb

```
<h1>Users#show</h1>

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>User:</b>
  <%= @user.user_profile.user_id %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Language:</b>
  <%= @user.user_profile.language_id %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Country:</b>
  <%= @user.user_profile.country_id %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Prefecture:</b>
  <%= @user.user_profile.prefecture_id %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Gender:</b>
  <%= @user.user_profile.gender_id %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Nickname:</b>
  <%= @user.user_profile.nickname %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Introduction:</b>
  <%= @user.user_profile.introduction %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Picture url:</b>
  <%= @user.user_profile.picture_url %>
</p>


<p>
  <b>Tag List:</b>
  <% @user.tags.each do |tag| %>
  <span><%= link_to tag.name, {:action=>'index', :tag=>tag.name} %></span>
<% end %>
</p>


<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div id="follow_user" data-user-id="<%= @user.id %>">
    <%= render :partial => "follow_user", :locals => {:user => @user} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

follows_controller.rb

```
class FollowsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :action=>"create.js"}
      end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.stop_following(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :action=>"destroy.js"}
  end
end

end
```

views/users/_follow_user.html.erb

```
<% unless user == current_user %>
    <% if current_user.following?(user) %>
        <%= button_to("Un-Follow", user_follow_path(user.to_param, current_user.get_follow(user).id), 
        :method => :delete, 
        :remote => true, 
        :class => 'btn') %>
    <% else %>
        <%= button_to("Follow", user_follows_path(user.to_param), 
        :remote => true, 
        :class => 'btn btn-primary') %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

views/follows/create.js.erb

```
$('.follow_user[data-user-id="<%=@user.id%>"]').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "follow_user", :locals => {:user => @user}) %>');
#jQuery
```

views/follows/destroy.js.erb

```
$('.follow_user[data-user-id="<%=@user.id%>"]').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "follow_user", :locals => {:user => @user}) %>');
#jQuery
```

views/users/index.html.erb

```
<%- model_class = User.new.class -%>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.pluralize %></h1>
</div>
  <% @from %>
  <h3>tag cloud</h3>
  <% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
    <%= link_to tag.name, {:action=>'index', :tag=>tag.name}, :class => css_class%>
  <% end %> 


<%= paginate @users %>

<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>  
      <div class="memberListBox">
        <div class="memberList">
            <p class="name"><span><%= user.user_profile.nickname %></span>(<%= user.user_profile.age %>)</p>
            <p class="size"><%= user.username %></p>
            <p class="img">
            <% if user.user_profile.user_avatar? %>
            <%= image_tag(user.user_profile.user_avatar.url(:thumb),:height => 100, :width => 100, :class => 'img-polaroid' ) %>
            <% else %>
            <%= image_tag('nophoto.gif',:height => 100, :width => 100, :class => 'img-polaroid' ) %>
            <% end %>
            </p>
            <div class="introduction">
                <%= user.user_profile.introduction %>
            </div>

<% if user_signed_in? && current_user!=user %>          
<div class="follow_user" data-user-id="<%= user.id %>">
  <%= render :partial => "follow_user", :locals => {:user => user} %>
</div>
<% end %>

  <%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i> ') + 'Message', new_messages_path(user.username), :class => 'btn btn-primary'  %>


                <%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> ') + 'Profile', show_user_path(:username => user.username, :breadcrumb => @from), :class => 'btn btn-info' %>              

        </div>
    </div>
   <% end %>
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View contains a DIV with `follow_user` **ID**.

JS partial is trying to select `follow_user` **class**.

```
# views/users/show.html.erb
<div id="follow_user"...

# views/follows/create.js.erb
$('.follow_user[data-user-id=...
```

I remember from your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13898891/1153362) that `follow` view partials are used sitewide, so you can't really change them. Therefore, change the `show` view to use a `follow_user` class:

```
# views/users/show.html.erb
<div class="follow_user"...
```

Comment: ahh now it works!! what's difference between class and id here???? why did I need to use class instead of id??

Comment: Classes (`.`) identify one or more elements, while an ID (`#`) identifies exactly one specific element. Elements can have both classes and an ID, with any number of classes, but never more than one ID. Class selectors `$('.selector')` select classes, and ID selectors `$('#selector') select IDs. Class selectors cannot select IDs or vice-versa. ... Don't forget to accept my answer if it works for you.

Comment: thanks for beautiful explanation!! so when using @ in view, we are supposed to use class instead of id. right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Classes and IDs deal with HTML elements only; Ruby, Rails, views, and `@` don't matter. I suggested using a class here because that JS snippet is reused on pages with more than one `follow_user` DIV (index page) so an ID doesn't make sense. You could easily use an ID if only one element was involved, but that isn't the case here.